# printing values of variables in logcat for debugging in android

Tags: android, logcat

I have variables/fields in my activity which are of type float.Is there any way to log there values in logcat as Log.w,Low.v,Log.i are not helping me...

Comment: Check the following link that will help you.


Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030856/is-there-a-limit-to-how-much-of-a-string-logcat-will-print)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Float.toString(myFloatVar));
```

Comment: It is giving me this error:- Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type float

Comment: @aromero , it is again giving me following error:- The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, float)

Comment: @ruchira sorry (again). Log.d takes first a "tag" and then the string of the message. This "tag" is used for filtering purposes. So for example, suppose you have an activity named "MyActivity", then you can tag all logs inside that activity with "MyActivity" and filter your logcat using this tag. Edited my answer.

Comment: What is the header file for log.d?

Answer (score 2):

`Log.d("tag", "Value: " + float);` it will convert to string

Answer (score 1):

Log.d("Value: " + Float.toString(myFloatVar));

Comment: Thanks! It worked.The only thing which I needed to remove was "+" sign. I used the syntax Log.d("Value: " Float.toString(myFloatVar));

Comment: @ruchira that expression has invalid syntax

Comment: @aromero but it  compiled without giving me error when I  removed "+" sign.

Comment: @ruchira Nice! the important is that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(variable_name));
```

for example if int x=10; then

```
Log.d("value of x is ", String.valueOf(x));
```

gives  10

Answer (score 1):

You can print float using String.format-

```
Log.d("TAG", String.format(Locale.US, "Value = %f", x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not use any kind of `toString` methods. Simply use string concatenation converted to template in Kotlin.

```
import android.util.Log
{...}
Log.d("my_debug", "my_vars: $my_var1 $my_var2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int maxLogStringSize = 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i <= veryLongString.length() / maxLogStringSize; i++) {
        int start = i * maxLogStringSize;
        int end = (i+1) * maxLogStringSize;
        end = end > veryLongString.length() ? veryLongString.length() : end;
        Log.i(TAG, veryLongString.substring(start, end));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can print values of variables in logcat like this.

```
val TAG = "MainActivity" 
val a:Int=5
val b:Int=6
val sname:String="Username"
Log.d(TAG,"Hello World")
Log.d(TAG,"Value of a : $a")
Log.d(TAG,"Addition of a+b : ${a+b}")
Log.d(TAG,"Value of sname : $sname")
```