# Cannot read whole file from assets

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read a plist file from my assets folder, but the file is read only to line 153 - not to the end. Can anyone help me and tell me why is this happening?

If i log do this `Log.v("ReadFromFile("filename.plist",this);` I'm getting content to 153-rd line. What am I missing, why I'm not getting the content of the whole file?
Here is my code:

```
public String ReadFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
        InputStream input;
        String text = null;
        try {
            input = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();

            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }
```

And the content of the file I'm trying to read is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>RecitorLabel</key>
        <string>abdul-rahman-al-sudais</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>A­bdul Rahman Al ­Soudais عبد الرحمن السديس</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-Fātiĥah (The Opener) - سورة الفاتحة</string>
    </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-Baqarah (The Cow) - سورة البقرة</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat 'Āli `Imrān (Family of Imran) - سورة آل عمران</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat An-Nisā' (The Women) - سورة النساء</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-Mā'idah (The Table Spread) - سورة المائدة </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>6</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-'An`ām (The Cattle) - سورة الأنعام </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-'A`rāf (The Heights) - سورة الأعراف  </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-'Anfāl (The Spoils of War) - سورة الأنفال</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat At-Tawbah (The Repentance) - سورة التوبة </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Yūnus (Jonah) - سورة يونس </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>11</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Hūd (Hud) - سورة هود</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>12</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Yūsuf (Joseph) - سورة يوسف</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>13</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Ar-Ra`d (The Thunder) - سورة الرعد    </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>14</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat 'Ibrāhīm (Abrahim) - سورة ابراهيم</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-Hijr (The Rocky Tract) - سورة الحجر</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat An-Naĥl (The Bee) - سورة النحل    </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>17</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-'Isrā' (The Night Journey) - سورة الإسراء   </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>18</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Al-Kahf (The Cave) - سورة الكهف   </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>19</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Maryam (Mary) - سورة مريم   </string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://yaislam.com/quran/mp3/</string>
        <key>New item</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Number</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Surat Ţāhā (Ta-Ha) - سورة طه   </string>
    </dict>
   </array>
</plist>
```

Comment: How are you confirming that it's only read to a certain line? Please be aware there is a limit to the length of messages displayed in LogCat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030856/is-there-a-limit-to-how-much-of-a-string-logcat-will-print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the possible issues with using `Log` for testing, you are making an invalid assumption about the behavior of `available()`. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> It is particularly important to realize that you must *not* use this method to size a container and assume that you can read the entirety of the stream without needing to resize the container.

The best solution is to move the file out of `assets/` and into `res/xml/`, then use `getXml()` on `Resources` to read it in. This will parse ~10x faster than parsing it other ways.

If you absolutely do need to have this in assets, or you need it as a full string for some reason, you need to loop, as is covered in [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

I put your file in assets by the name "text.xml" and i am able to read the full content in a string :-

```
String jsonString = null ;
    try{
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.xml");

    int size = is.available();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

    is.read(buffer);

    is.close();

    jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes, seems that Log cat doesn't display the full output. And the example content of the file is only a small fragment of the whole file. I've set the string output to a textview and the whole thing is shown. Thanks!

Comment: I gave my answer on the basis of your question. If the file is big you need to put up the whole file. My Logcat shows the full String.