# JSON array in object having 171 item not showing completely shows dots at last

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hey guys i am having problem with json array. in my code i am storing phone contacts to json array and putting that array in a object . But the probleme is that the array is not showing items completely it showing dots at last so that by json object is invalid object.Can you help me out following is my code and object.

```
      for (PhoneContact phoneContact : phoneContacts) {
               if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(phoneContact.getContactNumber())) {
                phoneContact.setStatus("POSTED");



        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                object.put("contactName", phoneContact.getContactName());
                object.put("phoneNumber",     
                PhoneUtil.getPhoneNumber(phoneContact.getContactNumber()));
                JSONObject userobj = new JSONObject();
                userobj.put(StringConstant.ID, mapper.getUserId());
                // JSONObject groupobj = new JSONObject();
                // groupobj.put(StringConstant.ID, groupId);
                object.put(StringConstant.USER, userobj);
                // object.put("Group", groupobj);
                phonenumbers.put(object);
            }
        }
        request.put("contactDetails", phonenumbers);
        request.put("isSync", Boolean.FALSE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(StringConstant.EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
    }
    return request;
   }


  Final JSONObject :

[
{
    "phoneNumber": "9822334455",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Sony Ericsson"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9823145808",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Samsung"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9822114455",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Inew"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "111",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vodafone Care"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "141",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Balance Info"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "140",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Recharge"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "121",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Best Deal"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "123",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Top Services"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "*444#",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Bonus Cards"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "198",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Complaints Only"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "*111#",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Self Help"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8421060095",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pallavi Mother"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9713344888",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pintu"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8421060094",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Sachin Mate"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9623461238",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Monu"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9552516847",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Prashant Korde"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7385863243",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Asiya"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "2024468994",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pallavi Home"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8087419790",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pallavi"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9730396745",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Narendra"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8097528780",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Deepak Kumar"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9732274869",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Jai"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "555555",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vid"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8087419790",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Palavi"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "88203",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Samtsb3"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8856903080",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Akash"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9405681761",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Akash Bar"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8827394156",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Rajju"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9730313075",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Kaushal"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9823054740",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pandey"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8888888807",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Banti Landge"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9890589289",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shirikant"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9969320485",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Akhiles Sir"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9049588154",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Bapu"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9822387529",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ehwar Varma"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7588285442",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vishnu Varma"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "2024489211",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Varma Shop"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7710002376",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shoumya"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9822271444",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Gait Yogesh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8087520296",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Grey"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8796568528",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Deepak"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8237797002",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Udaram Barsagad"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8552946297",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ram Barsagadey"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8928485985",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vijay Kumar"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "666666",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Celkon"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9730332839",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vinay"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8044804480",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Medical"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9370597136",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shiris Despande"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9029013326",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vinay Singh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9434824016",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Jai"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9827023816",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Sushi Tiwari"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9767718271",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Sachin Iternia"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9225652817",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Amir LIC"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9922827717",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Amit Desai"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9766643946",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Nagesh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7709645430",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vijendra"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9035897140",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Santosh Nigde"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7766889900",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Test"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "99439209",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ravi"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9405984826",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Bandu Mama"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8087579957",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vaishali"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9096966100",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pankaj Kamde"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9970341902",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Pankaj Kamde 2"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9421721146",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ashokh Bhau"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9822245024",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shailesh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7875011018",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Kuldeep"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9823338047",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Nagendra Bhange"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9011096507",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Parik"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9850831764",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vijay Jadhaw"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9767511714",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Kamlakar Jadhaw"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7798205667",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shebin"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9623215171",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Iphone Devrlope"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9039825551",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Jai Mother"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9545156178",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Prashanth Raghu"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7506062787",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vijay Shigh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9329844710",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Kartik Bhilai"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9766255660",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Rahul Electroni"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "2060502090",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Gsit Office"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7276044889",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shidhrth Plot"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9527192044",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ganesh"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9730079108",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Shailesh Gokhal"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9892577898",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "You Broadband"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "2024459381",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Woodland Shop"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7385502166",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Sachin Mate"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "7057474650",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Kamlakar Jadhaw"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9584618607",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Jai Mother"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9335344225",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Rani Didi"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9313643955",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "+919313643955"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "8806312405",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Vijendra Friend"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9890654329",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Koonal"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9263586247",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Ravi"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9860703945",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07dc5f146d"
    },
    "contactName": "Rajesh Patil"
},
{
    "phoneNumber": "9763674815",
    "user": {
        "id": "13888ff8-25a3-4d4b-a08a-4d07d...
```

Comment: Final JSONObject : is the result, which ur printing in the console..and ur not able to see the full response rt?

Comment: yes i am not able see the full object

Comment: i dont understand whats wrong with it

Comment: Ur json should be more than 1000 characters, after max limit exceeds console won't show remaining string

Comment: means it has a value but its not showing it

Comment: yes, I have posted answer. check it may help u

Comment: thanks harshavardhan but i am passing this object to server i am not printing it thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput("ur.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write("ur file name".getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

get the json from /data/data/urapp/files/ur.json read file.
IF you wan't to see in console it self then check this post [string-logcat-will-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030856/is-there-a-limit-to-how-much-of-a-string-logcat-will-print)